# Building a perl package with a custom PER5LIB

Tags: perl, cpan

Suppose I am building a perl package manually from its distribution file by executing the following shell commands:

```
tar zxf some.perl.dist.file.tgz
cd some.perl.dist
PERL5LIB=/my/special/perl/lib: perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/some/prefix
make install
```

The key point is running `perl Makefile.PL` with a custom PERL5LIB setting. Note, however, that I am only setting the PERL5LIB environment variable for the duration of the `perl Makefile.PL` command. I am not forcing it to be set during the `make install` command.

My question is: To what extent does the `make install` phase rely on `PERL*` environment variables being set that were also set during the `perl Makefile.PL` command run? If I set an environment variable like `PERL5LIB` during the `perl Makefile.PL` command should I also make sure it is set during the `make install` command?

What about distributions which use `Build.PL` instead of `Makefile.PL`? I've noticed some `Build.PL` distributions capture the `@INC` path used.

Answer (score 0):

`perl` is run by `make` and by `Build`.